# Are select()/poll() appropriate methods for a simple real time game server in C?

Tags: c, sockets, select, polling

I'm working on a simple multiplayer online text game and I read `select()` and `poll()` were popular methods for multiplexing I/O.

I found this [example in the GNU C docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html#Server-Example), which uses `select`. I ran it and made 3 Python test clients that look like this:

```
import socket
import time

port = 5555
test = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
test.connect(('localhost', port))

while 1:
    test.send('aaaa')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Then I ran the clients (from the same computer that's running the server) with different strings (`aaaa`, `55` and `..`).

The output of the server was

```
Server: got message: `aaaa'
Server: got message: `55aa'
Server: got message: `aaaa'
Server: got message: `55aa'
Server: got message: `..aa'
```

The strings were getting mixed up.

Is this some kind of silly compilation error, an error in my test clients or the fact that I'm running clients and servers from the same computer? Or is this program telling me I shouldn't use `select` for this purpose? Considering that I'll use this for a multiplayer game server (which probably gets lots of messages per second), I don't think I can let the messages get mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clients and server are completely asynchronous.  You don't know which is going to get time on the CPU and in which order.  The network also provides no guarantee about order of delivery (though TCP will ensure that the application sees data *from a single client* in the order it was sent).

Select/poll return a list of sockets that have data to read.  Make sure you read them all before calling select/poll again otherwise you will be prioritizing connections on lower-numbered ports.

Note that a read is raw data, not terminated in any way, and so cannot be dumped directly as a string unless the sender included a NUL terminator in the write to its socket.

Comment: I don't mind if the packages arrive out of order. The problem is, they're getting _mixed up_. If two messages get mixed up and I'm using feeding those messages to the game server as game commands, it might do something dumb, like "shooting 5 boxes to the left" or "eating a box".

Comment: Data from different clients will never get mixed up in the OS.  Each port is completely independent from all others.  I suspect what you're seeing is your **buffer not being cleared out between reads**.  It has 4 characters and then you read 2 into the first two bytes but the next two remain as they were from the previous read.  Socket reads return raw bytes; no terminating NUL is added to the read and your `send()` call is not transmitting one either.

Comment: The buffer used in the example is not allocated explicitly. It's a local variable of the function `read_from_client`. I even cleared the buffer adding a `bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer))` at the very end of the same function but the strings are still getting mixed up. You're completely right about the last part, though. I added a `\0` at the end of the `send` command and now it works. Please *edit* your answer so I can accept it. | Nevermind, I thought you were someone else. I'll accept your answer, thanks.